# Make a relation matrix and populate it

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name =
```

I want to store some values for each combination of model object. These value can change in time and they aren't linked by a math function.
What's the smartest way to do it?

Maybe I can use this model:

```
class Model_Relation(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='model1_relation')
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='model2_relation')
    value1 = models.ForeignKey(Something, to_field='name',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, default ='something1'
        related_name='...')
    value2 = models.ForeignKey(Anotherthing, to_field='name',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, default ='anotherthing1'
        related_name='...')
    value3 = ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("model1", "model2")
```

but to write all the relations it's very long...

It can help set a default on my populate_script

```
for m1 in model.all():
    for m2 in model.all():
        m1.name_m2.name = add_model_relation(m1, m2, 'something1', 
            'anotherthing1', '...')
```

and then change only where is necessary but it's anyway very long...

Maybe it's better add some field to Model or... I don't know... any advice?

Edit:
Using the through field:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
        related_name='...', through='Model_Relation')

class Model_Relation(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='model1_relation')
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='model2_relation')
    value1 = models.ForeignKey(Something, to_field='name',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, default ='something1'
        related_name='...')
    value2 = models.ForeignKey(Anotherthing, to_field='name',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, default ='anotherthing1'
        related_name='...')
    value3 = ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("model1", "model2")
```

What about doing three m2m, one for each value to add? So I can definite the relation only when and if it'll be necessary

Comment: Do you know about M2M relationship using through models? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Yes, but do you think it's better?

Comment: Yeah, for sure; this is the purpose of through models